# PostGIS not working?

Tags: postgis, postgresql-9.3

We just upgraded our Postgres installation from 9.1.6 to 9.3.9.
We have a nightly process that copies a database from a partner and restores it on our server.  There are geometry columns in that database.

I installed PostGIS through StackBuilder and I enabled the extension using

```
CREATE EXTENSION PostGIS
```

I verified that it was installed using

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version()
```

But I am getting errors when restoring the table that type 'geometry' does not exist.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I checked [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850500/postgis-installation-type-geometry-does-not-exist) and tried all of the solutions in that link.  Made sure public was in my search path...  But still no luck.

Comment: Find the first error, before "'geometry' does not exist".

Comment: Unfortunately that is the first error.

Comment: UPDATE : I made sure PostGIS was installed to the Public Database .  I ran GRANT ALL ON TABLE spatial_ref_sys TO myuser. The backup  script now runs successfully when I execute it from the command line.  When the windows Task Scheduler runs the python script however, I get the "type geometry does not exist" error.  The task runs as the same user I log in as.  I know Windows/Python/Postgres isn't the most common combination, but anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing these extensions as well:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: I haven't.  They weren't installed previously so I didn't think they were nescessary.  I can try.