# Connecting a Play! application to a postgres (with Postgis) database with Docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, playframework, docker, postgis, docker-compose

I'm trying to start my Play! 2.4 application using a Postgres database with Docker-compose.

I manage to start my Play! application alone (but it doesn't work since it can't connect to the database). And I also manage to start my postgis database using the image mdillon/postgis:9.4.

My **Dockerfile** is:

```
FROM mdillon/postgis:9.4

ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Here is my **init.sql** file:

```
CREATE USER simon WITH PASSWORD 'mySecretPassword';
ALTER USER simon WITH SUPERUSER;

CREATE DATABASE ticketapp;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE ticketapp TO simon;
\connect ticketapp simon
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

CREATE DATABASE tests;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE tests TO simon;
\connect tests simon
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

(I think that it is not necessary to create the extension as it seems to be already done.)

If I run my docker database and manually run the init.sql script, I can add a table with a Geometry type as a column.

Now comes my problem: if I try to link my two services with Docker-compose and the following **docker-compose.yml** file:

```
5.run:
  image: 5.run
  ports:
    - "88:88"
  links:
    - dbHost

dbHost:
  image: my_postgres
  ports:
    - "5433:5433"
  expose:
    - "5433"
```

I get the following errors:

```
dbHost_1 | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
dbHost_1 | ERROR:  relation "play_evolutions" does not exist at character 72
dbHost_1 | STATEMENT:  select id, hash, apply_script, revert_script, state, last_problem from play_evolutions where state like 'applying_%'
dbHost_1 | ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist at character 150
dbHost_1 | STATEMENT:  CREATE TABLE frenchCities (
dbHost_1 |  cityId                    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
dbHost_1 |  city                      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
dbHost_1 |  geographicPoint           GEOMETRY NOT NULL
dbHost_1 |  )
5.run_1  | [error] p.a.d.e.DefaultEvolutionsApi - ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist
5.run_1  |   Position: 150 [ERROR:0, SQLSTATE:42704]
```

Please note that my Play! application is correctly waiting the database to be ready.

Now I don't have any idea of what should be done in order to make it work, any clue would be great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgis installation: type "geometry" does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850500/postgis-installation-type-geometry-does-not-exist)

Comment: It is not a duplicate since I create the Postgis extension (although it does not seem to be needed, as said in my question) and I add the command ldconfig does not change anything.

Comment: I assume the `frenchCities` tables is in eiher the `tests` or `ticketapp` database? And yes you need to invoke `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` for every database that needs postgis support. Did you confirm your init.sql file works via pgadmin or psql?

Comment: Yes the frenchCities table is in the two databases (the schemas are the same). I was wondering if it is necessary to invoke `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` because I get a non fatal error `extension "postgis" already exists`. On the other hand I confirmed that my init.sql works via psql without any error.

Answer (score -2):

At fist I will show you how I config my db(edit file for conection) and then how I config it in play.

```
sudo su
apt-get install scala   //is important for play

apt-get -y install postgresql
sudo -u postgres psql
\password postgres

CREATE USER andi WITH PASSWORD 'pw';
create TABLE play OWNER TO andi;

\q
```

gui for postgres

```
apt-get -y install pgadmin3
```

**You have to edit the file(root access)**:
you have to write md5 in the following data.
You have to delete the comments in you data only for explaining.

```
/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf
```

here is deffiniert who and how they can log in

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5 // here

#here is deffiniert who and how they can log in
# TYPE DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

#here is deffiniert who and how they can log in# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
#here is deffiniert who and how they can log inlocal   all       all     md5 

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5 //and here
host    all             andi             127.0.0.1/32            md5 //and here


# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

***play***

**build.sbt**

```
import _root_.sbt.Keys._
import _root_.sbt._

name := """has"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaCore,
  javaJdbc,
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.6.0",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1102-jdbc41",
  "jp.t2v" %% "play2-auth" % "0.13.0",
  "jp.t2v" %% "play2-auth-test" % "0.13.0" % "test",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.3.5"
)
lazy val myProject = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

val appDependencies = Seq(
  "mimerender" %% "mimerender" % "0.1.2"
)
```

**conf/application.conf**

```
play.crypto.secret = "aKr4Mfn!vKzDjfhfdJRsakgbPS35!!HVDldkosGHRT"

# The application languages
play.i18n.langs = [ "en" ]
db.default.user=andi
db.default.password="pw"
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/play"

#The following line define define the model folder. You have to add a folder called models in the app folder.
ebean.default = "models.*"

# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR
play.evolutions.enabled=true
# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG
```

**project/plugins.sbt**

Normally you have only uncomment the last line.

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.4")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(SbtEbean). Note, uncommenting this line will automatically bring in
// Play enhancer, regardless of whether the line above is commented out or not.
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

I hope that this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I know how to connect my Play! application to a Postgres database since I already did it several times. My problem is to do it with Docker-compose.

Comment: @Simon I happen to have the same issue, did you by chance solved this error?

Since the application seems to be launched anyway, can it just be ignored ?