# Hibernate Spatial PostGis PSQLException column is of type point but expression is of type bytea

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, postgis, point, hibernate-spatial

In a Spring Boot project, Java8, with hibernate-spatial and PostgresDB 9.4

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG94Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG94Dialect
```

(I tried also PostgisPG9Dialect)

My Entity has a property

```
...
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
....
@Column(columnDefinition = "Point")
private Point cityLocation;
```

If I save with null value it's ok, but if I put a value

```
setCityLocation(new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(lng, lat));
```

I have:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: column "city_location" is of type point but expression is of type bytea  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

In my db I can see the column definition as

```
type: point
column size: 2147483647
data type: 1111
num prec radix:     10
char octet length: 2147483647
```

I'M GOING CRAZY... Why It doesn't work?

**UPDATE (It still don't work, I'm collecting new informations)**

1) I'm thinking the problem could be the creation of the db.
In my application.properties I also have :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

so the schema will update 'automatically' by hibernate.

2) I can run with success a query directly on the db (I use "Squirrel SQL" as client)

```
update my_table set city_location = POINT(-13,23) where id = 1
```

and if I

```
select city_location from my_table where id = 1
```

the answer is

```
<Other>
```

I can't see the value... I got the same answer for the record with null value inside the point type...

3) After set a value to the 'point' column with a query, I'm no more able to read from the table, I receive the exception:

```
org.geolatte.geom.codec.WktDecodeException : Wrong symbol at position: 1 in Wkt: (-13.0,23.0)
```

4) I look inside the hibernate-spatial-5.2.10.Final.jar and I found two "geolatte" named classes in the package org.hibernate.spatial :

GeolatteGeometryJavaTypeDescriptor.class
  GeolatteGeometryType.class

5) And also (specific for Squirrel SQL client experts):
if I try to change a value of a column in "my_table" (not the 'point' city_location but anyone of the other columns) I recive an error similar to the one I recive in java when I try to insert a point value:

```
Exception seen during check on DB. Exception was:
ERROR: operator does not exist: point = character varying
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Squirrel is made with java.. so I can accept this strange thing, may be it compose the query in a 'wrong' way, maybe it is connected to the value  I see when I make a select...

*Any ideas?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I found the solution!!**

A fix to the code was needed and a magic trick I read in another stackoverflow question saved my life.

The problem was that the db column was created in a wrong way:

in the db the column type should be **geometry**  NOT *point*

I removed the *columnDefinition = "Point"* from the @Column annotation and I ran the query

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

on my db following these instructions: 
[Postgis installation: type "geometry" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850500/postgis-installation-type-geometry-does-not-exist#answer-20974997)

[Krishna Sapkota](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3046889/krishna-sapkota) you are my new super hero!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `columnDefinition = "POINT"`, from `@Column` annotation, and just use the Point object. (i.e. Use default column definition)

Comment: This solution worked for me when using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.