# type "geometry" does not exist on schema, but extension does

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, database-schema

Note: Not a duplicate of [Postgis installation: type “geometry” does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850500/postgis-installation-type-geometry-does-not-exist)

I'm trying to create a table using Postgis geometric columns on a new schema called `test`.

First I ran:

```sql
SET search_path TO test;
```

Then when I try to run the following statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE spatials (id serial, name text, geo geometry, PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

I get the error `type "geometry" does not exist`

I've tried running both of the following:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
--AND:
CREATE EXTENSION postgis SCHEMA test;
```

But both result in the error `extension "postgis" already exists`

Note that it works fine when using the `public` schema.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like Postgis is installed in the `public` schema not in the `test` schema. To verify you can run

```
SELECT nspname
       FROM pg_extension ext
            INNER JOIN pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = ext.extnamespace
       WHERE ext.extname = 'postgis';
```

which will give you the schema Postgis is installed in.

Then schema qualify the type like `public.geometry` or with whatever schema Postgis is installed in.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to install the extension on multiple schemas?

Comment: To my knowledge no.

Comment: Yes you can: `DROP EXTENSION postgis; SET search_path to public; CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

Comment: @Kartik this will drop the extension and create it again in the `public` schema. I think it is not possible to have `posgis` extension in multiple schemas. But you can change the schema according to https://postgis.net/2017/11/07/tip-move-postgis-schema/