# How to restore a backupin in a different schema pgAdmin

Tags: postgis, database-schema, restore, pgadmin-4

I am struggling with a postgis database.

I have a backup from a public schema. I created a new database with the postgis extension. I now can restore the data into my postgis database and that works fine. I can rename that public schema to a new schema. That works fine too with:

`ALTER SCHEMA public RENAME TO new_schema`

But now I need to do this in an existing database. So my public schema has data in it and that may not be compromised. I tried a fresh database to do the trick with the ALTER SCHEMA. So, I imported it in an empty public schema, did alter it, and exported the new_schema. That seems to work, however the geometry gives me an error and no data is restored.

The geometry is originally: `geom public.geomtery`
By altering the schema, it is changed to: `geom new_schema.geomtery`

On importing I got this error message:

```
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  type "new_schema.geometry" does not exist
```

I am new to postgis and pgAdmin. I can change it manually back to `geom public.geometry`. But that feels odd to do and I think it is odd to have one schema and another mixed like this?

I did find this information ([Postgis installation: type "geometry" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850500/postgis-installation-type-geometry-does-not-exist)):

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS new_schema;

UPDATE pg_extension 
  SET extrelocatable = TRUE 
    WHERE extname = 'postgis';

ALTER EXTENSION postgis 
  SET SCHEMA new_schema;

SET search_path TO new_schema;
```

This could also be done in pgAdmin: RightMouse on Extensions(), choose Definition and alter the schema. But then the postgis data is only for the new_schema?

Hopefully someone can help me out a bit; I think I am missing something important and do not want to screw up the live database.

Stay safe and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I now know not to work in the public schema, but to create a schema for each project. So, the data shouldn't have be in the public schema in the first place. The geometry stays in the public schema and is accessible for each schema that way. I did rewrite the backup sql for new_schema and left the geometry as geom public.geomtery. I lost some primary keys, but did rewrite those (it is a simple counter only).

So I learned a bit more again.