# Postgis initialization not work on spring-boot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, postgis

I'm in trouble with Postgis and spring-boot.
Just a few details to explain the problem better. I have a Java spring-boot application, with flyway to manage the versioning on Postgres DB. My Postgres is on Docker Container.
I need to manipulate spatial data in this application, so I must use Postgis.
I run this docker-compose

```
postgresqldb:
  image: kartoza/postgis
  container_name: postgresqldb
  environment:
     POSTGRES_USER: ***
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ***
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
  networks:
    - product-net
```

and, following documentation, postgis extension should be enabled by default.
My application.yml is:

```
  datasource:
    password: ***
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    username: ***
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG10Dialect
    show-sql: true
    database: postgres
    # PotGIS configuration
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
    flyway:
      locations: classpath:/db/migration
```

But, when I start my SpringBoot Application, I get this error:

```
2023-07-18T18:08:31.601+02:00 ERROR 166900 --- [  restartedMain] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migration of schema "public" to version "3 - create new table comuni" failed! Changes successfully rolled back.
2023-07-18T18:08:31.635+02:00  WARN 166900 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Migration V3__create_new_table_comuni.sql failed
------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42704
Error Code : 0
Message    : ERROR: type "geometry" does not exist
  Posizione: 242
Location   : db/migration/V3__create_new_table_comuni.sql (C:\Users\DeathStar\Documents\DstS\enelx-tool-monitoraggio\target\classes\db\migration\V3__create_new_table_comuni.sql)
Line       : 1
Statement  : CREATE TABLE PLACES (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  prov_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  prov_istat_code VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  reg_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  reg_istat_code VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  geometry GEOMETRY(MultiPolygon, 4326) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (name, prov_name)
)

2023-07-18T18:08:31.635+02:00  INFO 166900 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-07-18T18:08:31.666+02:00  INFO 166900 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-07-18T18:08:31.686+02:00  INFO 166900 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-07-18T18:08:31.712+02:00  INFO 166900 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-07-18T18:08:31.762+02:00 ERROR 166900 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

It looks like Postgis extension didn't work. So I tried to apply a script on docker-compose to force Postgis to enable, in this way

```
  postgresqldb:
    image: kartoza/postgis
    container_name: postgresqldb
    environment:
       POSTGRES_USER: postgres
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - product-net
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

and init.sql:

```
DO $$ BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'say welcome...';
  SET search_path TO public;

  RAISE NOTICE 'create PostGIS...';
  CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;

  RAISE NOTICE 'say goodbye.';
END $$;
```

Of course, docker said to me "*extension "postgis" already exists, skipping*" so this step was useless.
To solve this, at the moment, I run the script manually and after I run manually SpringBoot application. But I would like to automate the process, how do I do it?

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850500/postgis-installation-type-geometry-does-not-exist?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top ?

Comment: As I said, currently to solve I run it manually, but I want to deliver only dockerfile, so should work alone.

Comment: To be honest I always installed it via liquibase or flyway script and it was working without any problems, did you try that way?

Comment: When I tried with flyway, I got a user permission error. so I didn't investigate more on it. Could this be a solution?

Comment: Sure, maybe your role just doesn't have permission to create extension.